# Django: inserted text into a text field sometime doesn't go trough after post

Tags: jquery, python, django, html, summernote

I have this weird bug that i can't replicate all the time. I have a html and with Jquery i populate a text field ([Summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote)). If i just populate the text, do nothing with it and i submit the form, sometimes the form field is, some time it goes trough just fine. Its like 30/70 ratio. But if i edit something, or even click on the text field it goes trough all the time. Has anyone encountered such behavior.

My form

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = modelname
        fields = ['field']
        widgets = {
            'notes': SummernoteInplaceWidget(attrs={'height': '600px'},),
        }
```

my html

```
     var string = (function() {/*
     {{ message }}
     */}).toString().match(/[^]*\/\*([^]*)\*\/\}$/)[1];

        $('#button').click(function () {
            $('#id_field').summernote('code', string );
        });
```

Edit 1:

```
class Klass(UpdateView):
    model = Model
    form_class = Class
    action = ''

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method=='POST' and 'approve' in request.POST:
            self.action = 'approve'
        else:
            self.action = 'reject'
        return super(ParticipationApproveReject, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = self.get_object()
        program = object.program
        if self.action == 'approve':
            template1 = EmailTemplate.objects.get()
                else:
                    template1 = EmailTemplate.objects.get()
                send_html_mail(template1.subject, form.instance.field, form.instance.email)
                messages.success(self.request, u'')
                self.object = form.save()
                self.object.approve()
                self.object.save()
                return redirect(self.get_success_url())
            else:
                return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        else:
            if self.action == 'approve':
            template2 = EmailTemplate.objects.get()
                else:
                    template1 = EmailTemplate.objects.get()
                send_html_mail(template1.subject, form.instance.field, form.instance.email)
                messages.success(self.request, u'')
                self.object = form.save()
                self.object.approve()
                self.object.save()
                return redirect(self.get_success_url())
            else:
                return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        program = self.get_object().program
        return reverse_lazy('**')
```

I have two different buttons depending on what i want to do, but in both cases the bug occurs. The text i want to load into my summernote is an email template.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a views.py file where the data is being posted in django
You need to have a request that posts for example
category_id = request.POST.get('category_name').Otherwise this is not a django question